# Keras: time per step increases with a filter on the number of samples, epoch time continues the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm implementing a simple sanity check model on Keras for some data I have. My training dataset is comprised of about 550 files, and each contributes to about 150 samples. Each training sample has the following signature:

```py
({'input_a': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
  'input_b': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)},
   TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)
)
```

Essentially, each training sample is made up of two inputs with shape (900, 1), and the target is a single (binary) label. The first step of my model is a concatenation of inputs into a (900, 2) Tensor.

The total number of training samples is about 70000.

As input to the model, I'm creating a tf.data.Dataset, and applying a few preparation steps:

1. `tf.Dataset.filter`: to filter some samples with invalid labels
2. `tf.Dataset.shuffle`
3. `tf.Dataset.filter`: **to undersample my training dataset**
4. `tf.Dataset.batch`

Step 3 is the most important in my question. To undersample my dataset I apply a simple function:

```py
def undersampling(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, drop_proba: Iterable[float]) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    def undersample_function(x, y):

        drop_prob_ = tf.constant(drop_proba)

        idx = y[0]

        p = drop_prob_[idx]
        v = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)

        return tf.math.greater_equal(v, p)

    return dataset.filter(undersample_function)
```

Essentially, the function accepts a a vector of probabilities `drop_prob` such that `drop_prob[l]` is the probability of dropping a sample with label `l` (the function is a bit convoluted, but it's the way I found to implement it as `Dataset.filter`). Using equal probabilities, say `drop_prob=[0.9, 0.9]`, I`ll be dropping about 90% of my samples.

Now, the thing is, I've been experimenting with different undersamplings for my dataset, in order to find a sweet spot between performance and training time, but when I undersample, **the epoch duration is the same, with time/step increasing instead**.

Keeping my `batch_size` fixed at 20000, for the complete dataset I have a total of 4 batches, and the following time for an average epoch:

```
Epoch 4/1000
1/4 [======>.......................] - ETA: 9s
2/4 [==============>...............] - ETA: 5s
3/4 [=====================>........] - ETA: 2s
4/4 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
4/4 [==============================] - 21s 6s/step
```

While if I undersample my dataset with a `drop_prob = [0.9, 0.9]` (That is, I'm getting rid of about 90% of the dataset), and keeping the same `batch_size` of 20000, I have 1 batch, and the following time for an average epoch:

```
Epoch 4/1000
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 22s 22s/step
```

Notice that while the number of batches is only 1, the epoch time is the same! It just takes longer to process the batch.

Now, as a sanity check, I tried a different way of undersampling, by filtering the files instead. So I selected about 55 of the training files (10%), to have a similar number of samples in a single batch, and removed the undersampling from the `tf.Dataset`. The epoch time decreates as expected:

```
Epoch 4/1000
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step
```

Note that the original dataset has 70014 training samples, while the undersampled dataset by means of tf.Dataset.filter had 6995 samples and the undersampled dataset by means of file filtering had 7018 samples, thus the numbers are consistent.

Much faster. In fact, it takes about 10% of the time as the epoch takes with the full dataset. So there is an issue with the way I'm performing undersampling (by using `tf.data.Dataset.filter`) when creating the `tf.Dataset`, I would like to ask for help to figure it out what is the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that most of the time is spent on the dataset operations rather than the network itself. From examining the evidence, my theory would be that if this is executed on GPU (dataset operations are executed on the CPU regardless) then the GPU has to wait for the dataset between batches.
So as the dataset operation always takes the same time, this is why on the progress bar it would seem that batches take longer.

If executed on a GPU, the right way to assert if this theory is correct is to observe the GPU utilization (you can use `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` as it runs, or better yet use `nvtop` or any other GPU monitoring tool). If there are times where the utilization (not memory! but utilization) is not close to 100%, then that would be an indicator that this is indeed the problem. Notice it should never drop from 90% even not for half a second.

To solve this, you should use the `Dataset.prefetch` as the last dataset operation in your code, this will cause the CPU to over-fetch batches so it has batches available for the network to use so it won't wait.

Comment: I did monitor with `nvtop` the training process, but did not pay much attention to GPU utilization. I seem to recall it being variable though, so you might be correct. However, what confuses me is why the dataset procedures are repeated (and thus taking processing time) every epoch. My guess is, since I'm using `reshuffle_each_iteration` of `tf.dataset.Dataset.shuffle`, it might be performing the dataset operations again.

I'll try `prefetch` and check if it helps, thanks

Comment: If it varied, go ahead and execute with `dataset.prefetch(2)` as the last thing you do on the dataset itself, and see if there is any improvement. Regarding the filtering process it will execute every time, it doesn't matter it happened on previous epochs - remember that epochs can be configured to be just slices of datasets, so there is no guarantee that epochs are the same... If you want to filter only one time, you'll have to do it before building your dataset object

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going for that solution, of filtering before creating the dataset object. Still, I'm curious to see if prefetch helps with the issue, because I much prefer integrating the filtering process to the dataset operations.

Comment: Let me just add something interesting that helped a lot with epoch time: moving from `from_generator` creating of the dataset to `from_tensor_slides`. It essentially cut the epoch time in half

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to try to `cache` the dataset after the second filtering. As the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache) say, you can either store it in memory or to a file. Basically, after the first iteration `tf` will save the dataset, which will be then reused: this should also imply that the first random filtering will determine the remaining samples, that will be the same for each epoch.

Otherwise, you can try the [rejection_resample](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#rejection_resample) function: I never tried it, but as far as I understand it implements a behaviour similar to you custom resampling function (increasing or decreasing the size of the dataset), perhaps faster.

As a side note: consider that the first training epoch is always the slowest because `tf` has to compile the model to obtain a static computational graph (or, at least, it compiles every piece of code that is wrapped in a `tf.function`.)